# Changing a welcome message from full name to just username (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to web developing and PHP. I'm creating a website with a member area and would like to display a Welcome "username" message. In my actual code there is a Welcome message displaying the Full Name of user. Can someone help me here? Below I'm pasting the code I'm using for my login.php and login-home.php (member's area). Thank you

---

**login.php**

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Login</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css" />
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<div class="logo_container"></div>
<div class='splash-container'>
    <div id='fg_membersite'>
        <form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <fieldset >
        <legend>Orcaly</legend>

        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
        <div class='container'>
            <label for='username' ></label><br/>
            <input type='text' placeholder="UserName"name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
            <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>
            <label for='password' ></label><br/>
            <input type='password' placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
            <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
        </div>

        <div class='container'>
            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
        </div>
        <div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
        <div class='register'><a href='register.php'>Register</a></div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        <!-- client-side Form Validations:
        Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        // <![CDATA[

            var frmvalidator  = new Validator("login");
            frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
            frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

            frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide your username");

            frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide the password");

        // ]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
Form Code End (see html-form-guide.com for more info.)
-->

</body>
</html>
```

---

**login-home.php**

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Home page</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo_container"></div>
    <div class='splash-container'>
        <div id='fg_membersite'>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Home Page</legend>
        <div class='confirmation'>Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!</div>
        <div class='confirmation'><a href='change-pwd.php'>Change password</a></div>
        <div class='register'><a href='access-controlled.php'>A sample 'members-only' page</a></div>
        <br>
        <div class='register'><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the data structure of `$fgmembersite` ?

Comment: In my fg_membersite.php:function UserFullName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
    }

Comment: In my fg_membersite.php:

Comment: function UserFullName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
    }

Comment: Is by chance this? https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm/blob/master/source/include/fg_membersite.php It's not really stellar code, and I see no way to get the username without making some changes to the class

Comment: yes it is exactly that one

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you need to change this line of code:

```
<div class='confirmation'>Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!</div>
```

So that $fgmembersite->UserFullName();   becomes a variable that holds your username or a function that returns your username.  Right now it is a function that returns the user's full name.

This might be a little bit beyond your current skills at programming.  One thing that is very simple and feasible is to store the username as a session variable when the user logs in.  Then you can replace $fgmembersite->UserFullName();  with $_SESSION["username"] or whatever you descide to call it.

Alternatively you can define your own function to return the username, or if the username isn't available for some reason, some other value (which is slightly better design).